# How to generate slug of a japanese text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to generate SEO friendy slug i.e "-" in every space in japanese text. For that in backend in have wrote a function

```
function slug($title){
    $slug = \Illuminate\Support\Str::slug($title);
    if(!$slug){
        $pattern = "/[$&+,:;=?@#|'\"<>.^*()%!-]/i";
        $slug = str_replace(' ','-',preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',preg_replace($pattern,'',strtolower(trim($title)))));
    }
    return $slug;
}
```

Now i want to implement same function in front as well in javascript. I have tried

```
var title = $(this).val();
title = title.toLowerCase()
                            .replace(/ /g,'-')
                            .replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'');
                            $('.slug').val(title);
```

but it only works for english text

Comment: Please provide a before and after example of the text you are trying to do this with. Otherwise, we can only guess at what you want.

Comment: @JLRishe above javascript code returns empty when japanese text is entered

Comment: **Please provide a before and after example** of an input and desired output. Without that, your question is incomplete.

Comment: convert string to ascii values or hex codes then replace the corresponding values.

Answer (score 1):

First. There's no space at Japanese, so I don't understand why you need to put hyphen into it. And Japanese sites doesn't have a standard to this. For example [Wikipedia JP](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%89%B9%E5%88%A5:%E6%96%B0%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8) uses Japanese as slug. While other sites such as [TV-Tokyo](https://www.tv-tokyo.co.jp/genre_anime/index.html) uses english as slugs.

However if you really want to have that. The easiest way is like this one, no Jquery needed

```
const autoCalcSlug = (word) =>
    word
    .toLowerCase()
    .trim()
    .replace(/ +/g, '_')
    .replace(/_+/g, '-')

console.log(autoCalcSlug('新しいページ ページ'))
console.log(autoCalcSlug('アニメ アニメ'))
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qc1j328h/15/

This should work mostly on both EN and JP characters.